# How to change channel dimension of an image?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have numpy array with `shape = [y,z,21]` where `y = image_width`, `z= image_height`. The above array represents image with 21 channels. How should I convert it to `size = [ y,z,3 ]` ?

Comment: What is the meaning of the 21 channels?  Is the data actually a stack of 21 grayscale images?  Or is it a stack of 7 RGB images (i.e. color images with three channels per image)?  Or something else?

Comment: I am working on Pascal voc 2012 dataset for semantic segmentation and as there are 21 classes present, each channel represents score of that particular class.

Comment: Are you trying to discard all but the first 3 classes? If so, you can use `arr[:,:,:3]`

Comment: I want to merge all the 21 channels

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? What does it mean to "merge" the numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...]`?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a score threshold to map every pixel in the image to one class, and every class has a color (which has RGB channels), so every pixel is a RGB value for its class.